# Installing latest version of R-base

Tags: apt, software-installation, r

I have been unsuccessfully trying to install the latest version (2.15.2) of **r-base**.  Apparently, **R** package `Rcpp` would not install for R version 2.14.1 - the version that installs for me.

I am not sure what/how/where to change my installation attempts which appear below.  Please note that I am using ubuntu-12.04.1-server-i386.

The current installed version is R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22):

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
r-base is already the newest version.
```

Including version information doesn't help:

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-base=2.15.1-5ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.15.1-5ubuntu1' for 'r-base' was not found
```

Changes based on CRAN Ubuntu instructions from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README:

1. Added to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

   ```
   deb http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu quantal/
   ```
2. Update and install

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install r-base
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
   or been moved out of Incoming.
   The following information may help to resolve the situation:

   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 2.15.2-1quantal2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: r-recommended (= 2.15.2-1quantal2) but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: @Salem, thanks for your comment.  Yes, I have tried "upgrade" but that doesn't upgrade "R" to its latest version.

Comment: If you need to check if `R-base` is indeed the 'latest' version, then install/update if not, see my answer, linked below. If you wish to stay current with the latest `R` releases, it's recommended that these come from `sid` (although you may wish to be cautious when basing your entire system on `sid`...). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r

Answer (score 44):

None of the above worked for me so I am copying the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093331/how-to-install-r-version-3-0

Uninstall old R:

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
```

Then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)/"
```

Then copy/paste these commands into the command line:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Which worked for me

Comment: That also worked for me (12.04).

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.10 and it does not work. I still face the same issue

Comment: This post might be getting a little outdated. In general, remove your old R with `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/R`, download the latest tarball from https://www.r-project.org/, extract it and follow the instructions in 'INSTALL' in the top-level directory

Comment: Still a problem, and still works on "Trusty". Thanks!

Comment: Why do you uninstall before upgrading? Why do you need `ppa:marutter/rdev`? The rest should be enough, here's [official documentation for Ubuntu repositories](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html).

Comment: correct except current R repos append "-cran35" to LSB naming so you probably need to do something like `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)-cran35/"`

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I did it;

As already mentioned in the question, I went through the steps in [UBUNTU PACKAGES FOR R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html) instructions to add the repository, and did a apt-get update, and then

```
apt-cache showpkg r-base
```

which would give something like

```
Package: r-base
Versions: 
3.0.2-1raring0 (/var/lib/apt/lists/cran.rstudio.com_bin_linux_ubuntu_raring_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/cran.rstudio.com_bin_linux_ubuntu_raring_Packages
                  MD5: 5787ca79ed716232c4cc2087ed9b425b

3.0.1-6raring0 (/var/lib/apt/lists/cran.rstudio.com_bin_linux_ubuntu_raring_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/cran.rstudio.com_bin_linux_ubuntu_raring_Packages
                  MD5: 5787ca79ed716232c4cc2087ed9b425b
```

and the I did a

```
 sudo apt-get install -f r-base=3.0.2-1raring0
```

and done.

Answer (score 4):

open the terminal and type `sudo -s`. Then open `source.list` by typing:

```
gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then, add these lines to the file:

```
deb http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu quetzal/
```

then save& exit gedit. In the terminal type

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9| sudo apt-key add -
```

then type

```
exit
```

then type these commands --one line at a time--.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

Comment: Why are you adding the line `deb http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu quetzal/` twice?

Answer (score 2):

In my system (without R installed) that versions installs correctly. So maybe the best option is to uninstall the old R and install the newer, passing the specific version you want. But before you do that, make a backup of your operating system. It can be difficult to reinstall old the packages after you remove them.

Also just a note: if you do `sudo apt-get install r-base=2.15.1-5ubuntu1` it will not find a package because the version is wrong. In that repo, the files are named, for example `r-base_2.15.2-1quantal2_all.deb`, so the correct version should be `r-base=2.15.2-1quantal2` or `r-base=2.15.2-1quantal2_all`, for example.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I  noticed, if you follow instructions on various R-websites, these will make you add a line to the Linux sources list  `/etc/apt/sources.list`

See, for example, this link: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-on-linux-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/

However, some Linux distros add a line to a separate file in this folder:
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

This can lead to the `you have held broken packages` error message.

I commented-out the line (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and added the correct R-repository using the Software Sources manager of my distro (Linux Mint 18.3)

This solved the problem.

Comment: For me, the /etc/apt/sources.list file had the lines
`deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/`
and
`deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/`.
It worked once I commented out the `focal-cran40` line.