# How do I install/upgrade r-base to the latest version?

Tags: software-installation, r

I am pretty new to Linux. I installed R-base in my Ubuntu 12.04 using the Software Center (which by default is r-2.14). I want to upgrade to/install R 3.02 or newer. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing latest version of R-base](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218708/installing-latest-version-of-r-base)

Comment: Personally, I would use anaconda/conda and work with R within the sandbox it provides rather than installing R on my system. https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html It is a very solid distribution and is kept very current.

Answer (score 27):

You need to [add R's repository](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) to your system:

1. Use your favorite text editor (I'm using `gedit` as an example) to open `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Add this line to the file (if this is slow, use [another mirror](http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html). You may also want to change `precise` into the codename for your Ubuntu version --- e.g., `trusty` for 14.04):

   ```
    deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/
   ```
3. Update the list of packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install the latest R-base (you can also use the software center again):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install r-base
   ```

Comment: Are there any changes in the second command for ubuntu 14.04 users?

Comment: @VineetKaushik yes, change `precise` to `quantal`.

Comment: @terdon You need a trailing slash after precise in step 2, as `precise/`. I know it's a bit different than most apt repositories, but that's how the instructions at cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu spell it out.

Comment: @DanielKessler does the slash make any differenece? Trailing slashes are usually optional and can be left out. The version name is just a directory in the repository so it really shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: At least on my rig, if you leave off the slash, apt complains about a malformed line

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.10, i have tried precise, trusty and quantal nothing seems to upgrade my r version. I have 3.0.2 r version installed. I need to update my rstudio and r version. Please help.

Comment: @ArunRaja upgrade your OS. 12.10 is 3 years old and no longer supported, you won't find updated packages for it.

Comment: to avoid warnings/errors about gpg keys, use secure apt: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/#secure-apt

Answer (score 3):

Having had to spend time figuring this out and forgetting how it works, and then having to figure it out again multiple times, here's a more complete answer that is future-proof.

1. Edit the `sources.list` file. This file contains the servers that `apt-get` consults to check whether software exists and where it can be downloaded from. One can edit the file using the following command:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   This requires the gedit editor. If you get an error, either install this (`sudo apt-get install gedit`) or use another editor like nano (`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`).
2. Find a working server to download R from that also has the version of R you are interested in. This often means that one has to look for the name of the latest Ubuntu release. [A list of releases is maintained on the Ubuntu website](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Look for the latest released version and use only the first word in its name without capitalization. For instance, for the 16.04 release, the full name is `Xenial Xerus` and the name to use is thus `xenial`. Thus, we add the following line to the `sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
   ```

   Note that the above line uses the rstudio.com mirror. One can choose another mirror from [this long list](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html) and appropriately alter the URL. For instance:

   ```
   deb http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
   ```
3. Save and close the file. After this, one can install the newest version using:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update # update apt-get's list of known releases 
   sudo apt-get install r-base # install the newest available version of R
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far are useful but they all omit the next step which is pretty much going to be required of anyone who intends to use R seriously. Quoted lines are from the canonical R Installation and Administration Manual:

> Users who need to compile R packages from source [e.g. package maintainers, or anyone installing packages with install.packages()] should also install the r-base-dev package:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

I think potential installers should be reading that Manual more carefully than the recommendations on this page have so far advised.

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the commands are

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu quantal/
```

*Note: the forward slash is required otherwise you get an error

```
sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Comment: What? Why `quantal` when http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ lists `trusty`?

Comment: Here's an Ansible task that can be used to accomplish this same task:

  - name: Add CRAN repository to APT repository list
    apt_repository: repo='deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu quantal/' state=present

Comment: to avoid warnings/errors about gpg keys, use secure apt: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/#secure-apt