# Unable to Install rpy2 on Ubuntu 14.04, missing R_ext/Rallocators.h:

Tags: 14.04, pip

I run `sudo pip install rpy2` and I get the following error output.

```
    ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:32:31: fatal error: R_ext/Rallocators.h: No such file or directory
     #include <R_ext/Rallocators.h>
                                   ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-8KDxsc/rpy2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-06pcwE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8KDxsc/rpy2
```

I did the best I could to install all relevant dependencies.  Here are my versions:

```
selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ R --version
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
```

Comment: How did you install R?

Comment: What version of rpy2 were you trying to install?  FWIW, I get a similar error trying to install rpy2-2.8.5 on top of R 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest / current release of rpy2 requires a more recent version of R (current latest release of R is 3.2.x)

Comment: Great!  I added  deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/ to my sources, updated and `sudo apt-get install r-base` fixed my problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/431380/how-to-install-upgrade-r-base-to-3-02