# Rstudio installation issue on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation

Any help on how to install rstudio for desktop on ubuntu 17.04 .

Thank you in advance

Comment: go to https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download2/

Comment: This is too broad. We deal with problems and I see no problem, Here is a topic to install from source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/862403/install-the-lastest-version-of-rstudio Just replace versions numbers if/when needed.  Nothing wrong wth that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Download the file from the Rstudio site, double click it, and it should launch Ubuntu Software. Hit install and it should be good to go.

If that doesn't work, you can try opening Terminal and executing `sudo dpkg -i [deb package filename]` to install it via the command line.

Comment: The issue was resolved by following the steps according to  https://www.datascienceriot.com/33/kris/. The only change  I did was using the Rstudio Desktop 1.0.143  instead  of rstudio-1.0.44.Many thanks to Kris Eberwein  and all of you who tried to help to figure  out such issue.