# How can I rectify the numerous error messages that appear when installing packages?

Tags: r

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with R (3.4.4)/RStudio (1.2.1335) and am having great difficulty in installing some packages.  For the purpose of this question, I will use the Tidyverse as an example.

Using RStudio, I run:

```
install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)
```

And after what looks like a good start ("trying X-package, downloading X-package..."), the installation then becomes plagued with error messages galore. (Note this happens regardless of whether I set `dependencies` to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.)

I have read the error messages' advice and followed the instructions and nothing changes.  I have spent literally hours researching ways online to figure this out and trying different methods (such as specifying folders/directories to store the packages to, reinstalling some software, removing other software, and several other things) and still nothing changes.

I have fully uninstalled and reinstalled R/RStudio and still the same thing occurs.

For example, when I run the above code, this is where things start to go wrong:

```
* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
/home/mus/.R/Makevars:1: *** missing separator. Stop.
/home/mus/.R/Makevars:1: *** missing separator. Stop.
/home/mus/.R/Makevars:1: *** missing separator. Stop.
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/mus/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘haven’ ...
** package ‘haven’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/home/mus/.R/Makevars:1: *** missing separator. Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘haven’
* removing ‘/home/mus/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/haven’
```

The length of this message is significantly larger - I have merely truncated it for the purpose of this question.

My question is this: what could I be missing here?  I don't think it should be so difficult to resolve, yet it is proving to be one of the single most complicated problems I have ever come up against and I cannot think of what it could possibly be.

Are there any tips and tricks that those of you who have had similar experiences can share?

How can I avoid these error messages?  (Note that this also happens when I try running the same command from the Terminal.)

Also, if it helps:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/mus/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"              
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                     "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use pre-compiled packages when available

As it is true for general packages, so it is true for R packages. Use Ubuntu's application package download and install system to get R packages.

To find out if a particular R package is available in the R-CRAN repositories, open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
apt-cache search tidyverse
```

You will see a list of packages associated with `tidyverse`:

```
r-cran-sjmisc - GNU R package "Data and Variable Transformation Functions"
r-cran-tidyverse - GNU R package "Easily Install and Load the 'Tidyverse'"
r-cran-tidyquant - GNU R package "Tidy Quantitative Financial Analysis"
r-cran-rlang - GNU R package "Functions for Base Types and Core R and
r-cran-tidyselect - GNU R package "Select from a Set of Strings"
r-cran-sugrrants - GNU R package "Supporting Graphs for Analysing Time
r-cran-tidyimpute - GNU R package "Imputation the Tidyverse Way"
r-cran-pivot - GNU R package "'SQL' PIVOT and UNPIVOT"
r-cran-tidycensus - GNU R package "Load US Census Boundary and Attribute Data
r-cran-janitor - GNU R package "Simple Tools for Examining and Cleaning
r-cran-areal - GNU R package "Areal Weighted Interpolation"
r-cran-moderndive - GNU R package "Tidyverse-Friendly Introductory Linear
```

The package you are looking for is second in the list. All R packages have the prefix `r-cran-`.

To install the R package, enter:

```
sudo apt install r-cran-tidyverse
```

You will be asked for your password. When you enter the password, the cursor will not move and you will not see *******. This is normal in Ubuntu.

Installing R packages in this way has two benefits:

1. It will keep fGarch up-to-date. Whenever fGarch is updated in R-Cran repository, it will be updated in your computer along with the system update process.
2. All users of this computer will be able to use the fGarch package within R and RStudio.

See [R and RStudio installation and package error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931375/r-and-rstudio-installation-and-package-error/931919#931919) for more details.

## The error:

The error you are seeing is because `curl` is not installed in your Ubuntu. Ubuntu uses `wget` while other distributions use `curl` to download system packages. When you are trying to install a package from within R (or RStudio) it is trying to install an Ubuntu system package `curl`. This does not work, as RStudio does not have `sudo` privileges.

To solve this problem, install `curl` at the Ubuntu system level by:

```
sudo apt install curl
```

This will install `curl` in Ubuntu and allow R to use `curl`.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a very good answer - thank you for taking the time to help; however, `apt-cache search tidyverse` results in `r-cran-rlang - Functions for Base Types and Core R and 'Tidyverse' Features
r-cran-tidyselect - GNU R select from a set of strings`.

Comment: Also, my installation of `curl` is already fully up-to-date / the newest version `(7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6)`.

Comment: You may need to add one of the R PPAs.

Comment: I have done some searching and can't seem to find what you mean.  Would you please provide some guidance here?

Comment: I used this instructions to install R 3.5: https://rtask.thinkr.fr/blog/installation-of-r-3-5-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/ This adds `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/` and `ppa:marutter/c2d4u3.5` as PPA repositories.

Comment: I followed the steps and realised that I could add `r-cran-tidyverse` to the list of packages to install via the CLI.  I then added the other packages via this method and all is working correctly.  I'm not entirely sure why this is but nevertheless, it works. Thank you.

Comment: @user681186 Once the packages are installed, how can I load them in RStudio? Foe example, I have just installed Tidyverse (`sudo apt install r-cran-anytime`); how can I now load it in RStudio?  I tried `library(tidyverse)` but it didn't work as I am told that the library doesn't exist.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy the `library(packagename)` should work. I am not familiar with `anytime` or `tidyverse`.

Comment: Apologies - I installed both `Tidyverse` and `anytime` and then went through RStudio trying `library(tidyverse)` and received `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/mus/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I tried restarting the machine and still got the same error message. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, I am out of my depth. I don't know what is going on.