# How to install R on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial?

Tags: 16.04, r

Is there a convenient shell script that allows you to install everything at once?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/919275/installing-rstudio-is-this-very-different-from-other-packages/919288#919288

Comment: @user68186 The other answer is a shell script that does everything for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. We need to add [R repository](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/), then install packages  from it:

   - 3.4.4

     ```
     cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list
     deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
     EOF
     sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
     ```
   - 4.0

     ```
     cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list
     deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran40/
     EOF
     sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
     ```
2. Download RStudio from [official site](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/), for example, [version 1.2.5042](https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/xenial/amd64/rstudio-1.2.5042-amd64.deb), and install it with `gdebi`:

   ```
   wget https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/xenial/amd64/rstudio-1.2.5042-amd64.deb
   sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-1.2.5042-amd64.deb
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Conveniently, there is, right [here](https://gist.github.com/mGalarnyk/41c887e921e712baf86fecc507b3afc7)!   The contents of this shell script:

```
# Install R + RStudio on Ubuntu 16.04

sudo apt-key adv –keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com –recv-keys E084DAB9

# Ubuntu 12.04: precise
# Ubuntu 14.04: trusty
# Ubuntu 16.04: xenial
# Basic format of next line deb https://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu <enter your ubuntu version>/
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev

# Download and Install RStudio
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-1.0.44-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-1.0.44-amd64.deb
rm rstudio-1.0.44-amd64.deb
```