# libreadline.so.6 issue in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: libraries, r

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 and cannot get R to run on it.  I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This issue seems to have come up before in similar situations:

- https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/Ubuntu1804ReadlineMess
- https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/542
- https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys/issues/643

I tried purging the library and R and then reinstalling them, with no luck.

This is not a duplicate of how to install R on ubuntu 16.04.  I could install R, but could not run it.  I had also installed R on previous ubuntu versions without problems.

One thing that might help: I have no problem running R on another computer where I installed ubuntu 18.04; the problem occurs on the computer where I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, so something about the upgrading process might be the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install R on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013160/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial)

Comment: I don't think so -- this is a guide to install R on Ubuntu.  I follows these instructions, and R installed, but I cannot run it.  I had R installed on previous Ubuntu versions before with no problem.

Comment: Why do you have all this stuff in `/usr/local`? How exactly did you installed R? If you used deb-packages then they were installed in ordinary folders and not to `/usr/local`. If you have compiled R, then it was wrong method. Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep "^ii\ \ r\-"` and `which R` to the question.

Comment: I followed these instructions: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been an issue with the upgrade.  I did not clean new install of Ubuntu 18.04 and then R, and the error disappeared.

Comment: What is the system for if you have to install it over and over. it is not toy story. It is Linx

Answer (score 13):

I also came across this issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, and after spending some time looking into the issue I found that after upgrade libreadline package was missing, so I installed libreadline package using

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

But this also didn't solve my problem. Then I figured out that it installed the upgraded version of the libreadline package i.e libreadline.so.7.0. As a workaround I created its symlink so I can continue my work with libreadline.so.6.

```
$ cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$ sudo ln -s libreadline.so.7.0 libreadline.so.6
```

And this worked wonders and my problem with libreadline package was solved.

Comment: I had to do `sudo ln -s libreadline.so.8.0 libreadline.so.6` but it basically solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `rm`, i.e.

```
$ rm libreadline.so.6
```

Then you can simply recreate the symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue installing R in Anaconda. This is seemingly related to older versions of R. [Symlinking to the newest version of `libreadline`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1209723/800704) created some error messages for me, so I'd thought I'd share [the solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1359017/800704) to install the "missing" version:

> `libreadline.so.6` is not provided by any official deb-packages in the Ubuntu repository, only Debian Jessie has package for it. If you want to save Anaconda - install this library manually by using commands below
>
> ````
> cd ~/Downloads
> wget -c wget
> http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/readline6/libreadline6_6.3-8+b3_amd64.deb
> wget -c
> http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.19-18+deb8u10_amd64.deb
> sudo apt install ./libreadline6_6.3-8+b3_amd64.deb 
> ./multiarch-support_2.19-18+deb8u10_amd64.deb ```
> ````

Comment: You probably installed ’r’ instead of ’r-base’ with anaconda, as stated here: https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/13439#issuecomment-475045926

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to miss-match installation. Please check operating system version and install correct application version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).