# Error when installing RStudio in Anaconda: `/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6:

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio

I am currently trying install Anacondas RStudio version. Already I have R installed from the official [CRAN repositories](https://cran.r-project.org) through apt package manager and the newest version of RStudio. My current version of R is installed in `/usr/lib/R` and the path variable set in `/usr/bin/R`. When running Anaconda Navigator's RStudio installer, it attempts to install a separate version of R in `/opt/anaconda3/lib/R`. The installation process hung and, now I am unable to type R in terminal and open the "old" R version. Instead I get the following error message:

```sh
$ R
/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried updating path variable for "old" R, but since `/opt/anaconda3/bin` is prior to `usr/bin` in the path list I still get the same error:

```sh
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/R
$ echo $PATH
/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/mplusdemo:/usr/bin/R
```

Firstly, I am uncertain what this error means. What is `libreadline.so.6`? How can I resolve this?

Secondly, do I need to, and is it advised to install R via Anaconda? My current version is updated from the CRAN repos, meaning I get the updates when they're available. Conversely, how up to date is Anacondas version? Alternatively, would it be wise to create a symlink to directory `usr/bin/R` in `/opt/anaconda3/bin`?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why do you think you need Anaconda on top of mature APT deb-packaging system? Normal RStudio is [packaged](https://rstudio.org/download/latest/stable/desktop/bionic/rstudio-latest-amd64.deb), R can install packages to `~/R` in your home folder. Which winning point do you get by using Anaconda?

Comment: My version is 20.04 LTS. I didn't think I need it, my "winning point" was that I thought it be neat to use Anaconda as hub for the programming tools I need, to "gather everything in one place" so to speak. As stated, my current version (4.1.1) is installed and updated from CRAN repos. I also has the latest version of RStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library named `libreadline.so.6` is not provided by any official deb-packages in the [Ubuntu repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libreadline.so.6), only Debian Jessie has [package for it](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&arch=amd64&mode=path&searchon=contents&keywords=libreadline.so.6). If you want to save Anaconda - install this library manually by using commands below

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/readline6/libreadline6_6.3-8+b3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.19-18+deb8u10_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libreadline6_6.3-8+b3_amd64.deb  ./multiarch-support_2.19-18+deb8u10_amd64.deb
```

and then retry launching R from Anaconda.

Update is below.

#### 1. Fixes for libraries

Installing `libreadline.so.6` removed OP's error message, but lead to a second:

```
$ /opt/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/R
/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This error was resolved by [installing the missing library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libncurses.so.5) :

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install libncurses5
```

This removed the error messages, and it was now possible to run Anaconda's R version from terminal.

> ```sh
> $ /opt/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/R
> R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
> ```

Still it did not resolve the issue of installation of RStudio hanging. This is seemingly related to [not having created an R environment createdd first](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11476#issuecomment-650988875). Following [this tutorial](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/create-r-environment/), the installation of RStudio was completed.

##### 2. Running the latest version of R and RStudio from Anaconda Navigator

After installation it became clear that both Anaconda's R and RStudio version are quite outdated. I find it better to have both downloaded and updated from their official repos:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
```

Recreating the path to CRAN's version of R, was a simple matter of removing the symbolic link `/opt/anaconda3/bin/R` from path.

```sh
sudo rm /opt/anaconda3/bin/R
```

As for running the newest version of RStudio (which was alredy pre-installed) within Anaconda was a simple matter of removing the existing symlink from Anaconda's RStudio directory, and creating a new one directing to the "old" installation directory:

```sh
sudo rm /opt/anaconda3/envs/renv/bin/rstudio
ln -s /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio /opt/anaconda3/envs/renv/bin/rstudio
```

This last step enabled running the latest version of R and RStudio from Anaconda.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I already have R and RStudio installed. I was actually just trying to add RStudio in Anaconda, so that I can use it as a hub. I had no idea when I started that it would try install another version of R in its own directory.

Comment: By the way `libreadline.so.6` is not provided by any official Ubuntu package. Possible solutions are - install this library manually from Debian Jessie. See updated answer.

Comment: This was sort of my point aside from understanding/fixing the error: Does Anaconda provide an up-to-date version of R and RStudio? If not, can I access my current installs from Anaconda somehow?

Comment: R executable from Anaconda installation needs `libreadline.so.6` , to get it fixed you have to install single deb-package by using 4 commands above.

Comment: @PålBjartan I edited your edit. But then it seems that your Anaconda installation is outdated. For me it is strange that it ships very old R 3.2.2.

Comment: I agree it seems odd it runs 3.2.2. I forgot to mention it installs 3.6 with RStudio. You are correct: Anaconda is messy. Updating Anaconda was the first thing I tried after you initial post, running `conda update anaconda` in terminal. Is this the correct command?

Comment: I do not use Anaconda to keep my system clean and functional, try to find/use their official documentation.