# Pandoc Markdown error

Tags: 21.04, anaconda, rstudio, markdown

I tried to complile a markdown document into RStudio, but when I knit it I get the following output:

```
/home/argus/anaconda3/envs/R-lab/bin/pandoc/pandoc: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error in system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) : 
  error in running command
Calls: <Anonymous> ... get_pandoc_version -> with_pandoc_safe_environment -> force -> system
Execution halted
```

I've read some post and I tried installing `sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev` and does not work, but I don't know if the error is related with pandoc or with libgmp.

Comment: Why do you think you need Anaconda on top of mature APT deb-packaging system? Normal RStudio is packaged, R can install packages to ~/R in your home folder. Which winning point do you get by using Anaconda? See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1359017/66509) for possible solution.

Comment: I use Spyder to Python programming, Then I saw that Anaconda also has RStudio. RStudio runing into Anaconda is the main problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You can get *libgmp.so.3* library from previous Ubuntu version by using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gmp4/libgmp3c2_4.3.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libgmp3c2_4.3.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

As you already see, using R and RStudio from Anaconda creates a mess instead of useful configuration.

More reproducible way is to remove Anaconda fully (or at least from $PATH) and then install complete R with RStudio using deb-packages as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
```

and then retry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work, the output was ```couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)```

Comment: It is just a warning. Retry package installation and then check existence of original problem.