# Error: Opening the cache (E:type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, r

I'm trying to install R. I tried the instructions from the best answer on [a previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013160), without success. I'm using ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS 64-bit.

I tried the method but my terminal window seemed to do nothing, even though when I tried to close the window it says there were processes running. I tried it a few times. And now I have an error message in the thin grey tray up top:

```
An error occurred, please run the package manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.
```

The error message was:

```
Error: Opening the cache (E:type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list,   
E:The list of sources could not be read.)

This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
```

Starting the package manager (through the notification) didn't do anything, i got this message (image attached):

```
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list/etc/apt
sources.list.d/r-cran.list  
E: The list of sources could not be read. Go to the repository dialogue to correct the problem.  
E:_cache->open()failed, please report.
```

I don't know how to go to the repository, or how to report. How do I fix this issue?

I also tried the instructions on [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) as well, copying the source and pasting into a terminal, which is probably not how to do this, but I don't know how to access the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

@heynnema when I ran the code it says 
cat:  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list: No such file or directory

@heynnema the fix didn't work here is the output from terminal:

```
(gedit:2641): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gedit:2641): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-enabled not supported

** (gedit:2641): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported

** (gedit:2641): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-enabled not supported

** (gedit:2641): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported

** (gedit:2641): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
helwalaura@Galactica:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
Executing: /tmp/tmp.L1dGqRuvRD/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-keys
E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key E084DAB9: public key "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
helwalaura@Galactica:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
helwalaura@Galactica:~$
```

@heynemma here is the result from `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list`

helwalaura@Galactica:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list
sudo cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/
```

@heynnema when I deleted the other 2 lines of code, this showed up in terminal window:

```
(gedit:3157): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gedit:3157): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-enabled not supported

** (gedit:3157): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported

** (gedit:3157): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me the `terminal` output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list` and then I can tell you how to fix it. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: In the link that you were following, what step of the install instructions were you at? It looks like you failed at the first step. When you respond, use the comments, not an edit to your question, as I almost missed your response.

Comment: @heynnema sorry about that!  I am new to using this website too!  Yes I messed it up from the get-go.  I did not know where to install the code: i think I typed what was supposed to go into the repository, into the terminal window.  I tried adding this to the "Other Software" section in updates, and it still doesn't work:

deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/

I think I've messed up the repository.  Would It help if i showed the terminal command history- to try to fix the original mistake I made?

Comment: We were all noobies once :-) Let's start with the very basics... now here's the part where you DO place this output as an edit to your question... In `terminal`, show me the output of `grep -i cran /etc/apt/sources.list` and `grep -i cran /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. Copy/paste this output into your question, select the pasted text, then click the `{}` icon to format that text into human-readable.

Comment: @heynnema I am at work, responding as quickly as I can.

Comment: @heynnema nothing happened with either code.

Comment: @heynnema thank you!  trying it now.  related question- I am running 16.04, when i upgrade to 18.04 will I have to reinstall all of this?

Comment: @LauraThomson You'll at least need to re-edit the r-cran.list file with the info from your 2nd link... `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try and pick up the pieces, we'll start from the beginning... this should get you started... use copy/paste with the following lines, as some of them are very long...

Note: Some/all of these "R" packages are in the Ubuntu 19.10 repositories.

In `terminal`...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list`

Add this as the only line in the file...

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/
```

Save the file and quit gedit.

In `terminal`... copy/paste one command at a time into `terminal`... first command is long...

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

Source: [How to install R on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013160)

Source: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html

**Update #1:**

Leftovers... but easy fixes...

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Go to `gedit` prefs, and enable line numbering.

Go to the very end of the file (line 52) and you'll probably find a line like this...

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/
```

Delete that line. Save the file and quit `gedit`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

And we should be done!

Comment: @heynemma, it didn't work.  will copy and paste into my post as per your message above.

Comment: @LauraThomson Show me `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list`.

Comment: @LauraThomson Re-edit the first file, and remove lines 1 & 2, so it should only have `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/` line in the file. Then do the last two commands in my answer.

Comment: @LauraThomson That's better. Those are just warnings, and they're just noise. Did the last two commands work now?

Comment: @@heynemma, there are a lot of updates.  then some notes about how some packages and translations are configured multiple times?  I haven't run the very last line of code yet. wanted to see what this meant, first.  :)

Comment: @LauraThomson You have more problems with your .list files. Edit your question with the terminal output of the `sudo apt-get update` command.

Comment: @LauraThomson not yet... we just have to solve all of the sins of the past :-)

Comment: @LauraThomson Show me the last output.

Comment: I can't post the output, I have run out of links. :(

Comment: @LauraThomson What do you mean? You should be able to edit your question.

Comment: I tried posting all the code in and when I try to save my edit on the question, I can't- it says i need more than 10 reputation to post more than 8 links.

Comment: @LauraThomson Then paste them at https://paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL

Comment: here it is:  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/697w6TFfmZ/

I'm headed home, will be offline for a bit.  Will log back in asap.

Comment: @LauraThomson Status please. Did you complete Update #1?

Comment: had to take a mental health day yesterday.  I did- it fixed a problem I didn't know I had- my screw up was blocking my update ability, including the option to upgrade to 18.04.  so I did the entire system upgrade and it seems to have fixed the problem in the process.   Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: I'm going to try to install r-base now.

Comment: @LauraThomson Great news! Thanks for the update. We all need mental health days now and then :-) Please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks! Also remember to update your r-cran.list file if you've updated to 18.04.

Comment: especially these days! :)  doesn't my r-cran.list file automatically update, when the system updates?  or do I need to run the <<  sudo apt get-update >> command again?

Comment: @LauraThomson because the `deb` line in your r-cran.list is Ubuntu-release-specific, you'll need to update as per my earlier comment, then do the `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` commands again, to get the latest "R" updates.

Comment: it worked!  R and Rstudio installed successfully!!  thank you so much for your help!!!!!  :)

Comment: @LauraThomson Great news! Thanks for the update!