# How to install glmnet on R 3.2.3

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, glibc

i need to install glmnet package for my R, but it said it doesn't support the version i installed (3.2.3).

I have tried to install R 3.6. the problem i am facing is that to install R 3.6, i need **libc6** > 2.29 but my libc6 is 2.23. I have searched online that it is not recommended to change your libc6 version since most of the apps are dependent on it.

Is there any workaround? 
For example, install an older version of glmnet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install R on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013160/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial) and check https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: R3.6 should be available for all supported Ubuntu releases from CRAN: see [UBUNTU PACKAGES FOR R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html)

Comment: @zifanyan see [updated answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013171/66509) - you can install R 4.0 and then install [`glmnet`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) on it using `install.packages('glmnet')`.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. What i did was to install an older version of glmnet from the archive. I did not manage to upgrade my R 3.23 to 3.6 or 4.0 because R 3.6 or later require a newer version of libc6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i did not choose to update my libc6 to a newer version to support the R 4.0 because change in libc can cause some problems.

What i did was to look for a older version of glmnet from the archive and installed it with my older version of R (3.2.3) and it worked perfectly!