# Problems installing libjpeg62 in ubuntu 16.04 E: Unmet dependencies

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dependencies

I was following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862403/install-the-lastest-version-of-rstudio) in order to install R and Rstudio, I could Install R just fine, but in preparation of installing RSTUDIO I tried to install libjpeg62 by doing

```
sudo apt install libjpeg62
```

but I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libjpeg62 is already the newest version (1:6b2-2).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 : Breaks: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 (!= 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1) but 0.10.36-2 is to be installed
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 : Breaks: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (!= 0.10.36-2) but 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
libgstreamer0.10-0 : Breaks: libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 (!= 0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1) but 0.10.36-1.5 is to be installed
libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 : Breaks: libgstreamer0.10-0 (!= 0.10.36-1.5) but 0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I tried to do that:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

but at the end of procecing I got

```
Preparing to unpack .../libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 (0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1) over (0.10.36-1.5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libgstreamer0.10-0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libgstreamer0.10-0:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libgstreamer-plugins-       base0.10-0_0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 (0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1) over (0.10.36-2) ...
 dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
  trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of      package libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386
 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1_i386.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do

Comment: I read it that you have been told you need libjpeg62; and your system is reporting the latest version is already installed; and you are then trying to force it; happy to be told I am wrong

Comment: You are right, i messed up, the problem is further ahead, can I ask you about mu next porblem here?

Comment: so you are using 16.04 and 32bit?

Comment: Errors where made, I realized now, I fixed it by reinstalling ubuntu and starting all over

Comment: I hope it is all working for you now; if so, great.

Comment: Yes it is @pdc thabks for the concern