# broken dependencies in Ubuntu 16.04 Package libgstreamer0.10-0:amd64 is not configured yet

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, rstudio

I am trying to install RStudio in ubuntu 16.04 following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862403/install-the-lastest-version-of-rstudio), I already intalled r, but I have problems installing RStudio

I did this:

```
wget --tries=3 --timeout=120 https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-1.1.383-amd64.deb
```

Followed by this:

```
 sudo dpkg -i rstudio-*-amd64.deb
```

and I got this error

```
(Reading database ... 224796 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack rstudio-1.1.383-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio (1.1.383) over (1.1.383) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rstudio:
 rstudio depends on libgstreamer0.10-0; however:
  Package libgstreamer0.10-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 rstudio depends on libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0; however:
  Package libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rstudio (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1)     ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rstudio
```

I understand that there are some packages that are not well configured, what does that mean, how do I fix that.

I thought maybe if I updated ubuntu it would work so I did

```
sudo apt-get update
```

got this

```
Hit:1 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Fetched 306 kB in 1s (279 kB/s)                                    
Reading package lists... Done
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 : Breaks: libgstreamer-plugins-    base0.10-0:i386 (!= 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1) but 0.10.36-2 is installed
 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 : Breaks: libgstreamer-plugins-    base0.10-0 (!= 0.10.36-2) but 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1 is installed
 libgstreamer0.10-0 : Breaks: libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 (!= 0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1) but 0.10.36-1.5 is installed
 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 : Breaks: libgstreamer0.10-0 (!= 0.10.36-1.5) but 0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1 is installed
```

E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

What should I do, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You installed *four* incompatible versions of `libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0`. Perhaps somebody has been abusing --force? Uninstall three of them.

Comment: You should try `apt-get install -f` and *gdebi* for installation of RStudio (`sudo gdebi rstudio-*-amd64.deb`).