# Unable to install R 3.5.0 in Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (18.04)

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, r

I was delighted to hear that R developers finally shipped R 3.5 through their CRAN mirrors and decided to install it immediately.I added the requisite PPA as mentioned in the CRAN website,`deb https://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/` but after running the command`sudo apt-get update`,I found the following warning.

`expected bionic-cran35/ but got bionic`

The screenshot is attached here for further clarity. 
[R_Bionic_installation_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1MZ7.png)

I was too optimistic and went on with the next code`sudo apt-get install r-base` and as expected, the installation failed.  The errors are shown here.

```
   Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.5.0-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It is worth mentioning that it is not a secure APT related problem and I had already added the required apt-key . Also, I do not have any previous R installation in my system.I need the updated version out there.(The R in Bionic Universe is still 3.4.4)

Am I missing something?

UPDATE : The bug has been fixed by Michael Rutter and his Debian team. A big thanks to everyone involved.

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver  for your quick response. I have edited the question with the required error codes.Please note that I am trying to install base R with `sudo apt-get install r-base` code.

Comment: It seems that you should [contact Michael Rutter](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html#acknowledgements) and inform him about two problems - warning `W: Conflicting distribution: http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease (expected bionic-cran35/ but got bionic)` and dependency problem while installing `r-base`. As temporary solution you can use *marutter* PPA as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1042871/66509).

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert for the suggestion. Sure, I will send a mail to the mailing list.

Answer (score 10):

I am posting this answer so that it might help someone stumbling over the same problem. The problem was solved with a roundabout trick - it was experimental but it did work out.

So, I was trying to install R 3.5.0 from CRAN directly and it refused to get installed as mentioned in the question. The idea was to install whatever existing version in Ubuntu Bionic (18.04) and upgrade to 3.5.0 (instead of installing R from scratch).

The detailed steps are :

1. For now remove the source
   `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/` from Software sources.
2. Basic cleanup :-

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
3. Install whatever existing version in Ubuntu Bionic with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install r-base
   ```
4. Re-add the source `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/`
5. `sudo apt-get update`

   -- still shows the warning `expected bionic-cran35/ but got bionic`

   Ignore and proceed with `sudo apt-get upgrade`
6. Upgrade all the existing packages in Linux

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

And the last command (6th)  actually does the job --- R 3.5.0.

PS - The warning still displays in the screen when I update the sources but right now appears to be innocuous. Hopefully the next R update will fix that.

UPDATE : Infact, the bug has been fixed. So we can directly install R as per CRAN website from now on.

Comment: This helped me: https://www.r-bloggers.com/installation-of-r-3-5-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/

Comment: Same problem cropped up again when I try installing R4.0.1. In short on my brand new Ubuntu 18.04 instance I added the line `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/` in the `/etc/apt/sources` and ran `sudo apt-get install r-base`. It installed "R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)". What is the problem please and is there a separate solution for R 4.0.1?

Comment: @user30994 In terminal, do you get `The following signatures couldn't be verified ... ` error? If so, then check the `Secure APT` section of https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/