# Broken Again - Unable to install R 3.5.0 in Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (18.04)

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, r

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046289/unable-to-install-r-3-5-0-in-ubuntu-bionic-beaver-18-04) from @pineapple explains a previous issue where the user was unable to install R 3.5.0 in Ubuntu 18.04 using the following process:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/ bionic-backports main restricted universe"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

Pineapple added an update to the question stating, *"UPDATE : The bug has been fixed by Michael Rutter and his Debian team. A big thanks to everyone involved."*.

When I try and install R 3.5.0 on my Bionic Beaver box I get this string of errors after issuing the `sudo apt-get update` command. Is the issue truly solved? How do I solve it?

```
Err:10 https://cloud.r-project.org bionic-backports Release
404  Not Found [IP: 52.84.35.214 443]
Reading package lists... Done    
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org bionic-backports Release' 
does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: I think, you read or do something wrong. Please read install documentation from project web page, here: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install R 3.5.0 in Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046289/unable-to-install-r-3-5-0-in-ubuntu-bionic-beaver-18-04)

Comment: @N0rbert disagree because the issue addressed in that post is different.  They also reference that question in their post already, and are looking for additional support because they followed an answer over there and are getting 404 errors now when `apt-get update` is run.

Comment: Retracted close vote. Seems to be new issue. Thank you, @ThomasWard !

Comment: Same issue, but I followed this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04), and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the instructions you followed are wrong, or you made a mistake, in either case you did something that you shouldn't have.

The second `add-apt-repository` command you entered is incorrect and wrong.  `bionic-backports` is a software repository in the Ubuntu repositories, *not* the R Project cloud repository.  This is the basis for that 404 error, so you will need to go into `/etc/apt/sources.list` and find where that line got added, and either remove that line or comment it out.  (My suggestion is to just remove the line since it won't ever work)

Further, the `bionic-backports` repository should already be enabled by default (but set to a lower priority than the rest of the repositories).  You shouldn't have to do the `add-apt-repository` command at all.  If a backported version of software is needed, then the R installer(s) should be referring to a version of the software in the backports repo, and should automatically get installed.