# Unable to install R on 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I tried installing R on 16.04 LTS and I get the below error. I tried all possible solutions given in various forums with no luck. Please suggest.

```
sak@bav:~$ sudo apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have 
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution
that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.5.1-1xenial) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: r-recommended (= 3.5.1-1xenial) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: did you read the output? did you try manually installing the dependencies yourself instead of relying on apt-get to do it for you?

Comment: i just picked one package required - https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/r-recommended  which says the 16.04 sources provide 3.2.3-4; your package wants 3.5.1 which only 'comic' has (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=recommended) so your 'r-base' isn't from a standard source.  You'll thus have to source deps from that source, or elsewhere too

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install -f` and see if that resolves your problem

Comment: Sorry people..i have no idea on 3.4 and 3.5 etc...i just followed this link
[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862403/install-the-lastest-version-of-rstudio).
initially my update did fail but after fixing sources.list  update ent fine..now i get this error..i tried @wjandrea suggestion too but i still get error