# Trying to upgrade R, error message refers to 'unmet dependencies'

Tags: software-installation, r

I tried following the directions in this post [Installing latest version of R-base](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218708/installing-latest-version-of-r-base) after several simpler techniques failed to upgrade my R (which is stuck on 3.0.2). Everything seems to have worked until the last instruction: `sudo apt-get install r-base`, which led to this message:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-108:/srv/shiny-server/atomic_junctions$ sudo apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.2.2-1precise0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.2.2-1precise0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I thought this meant I needed to install the mentioned dependencies. I kept getting more and more errors relating to one package needing another until I gave up when trying this:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-core r-recommended r-base-html r-base-dev
```

which still leads to errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libtiff4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So now I just don't have R installed at all. I need to upgrade as some packages I am using are not available for this old version of R. Any help/recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try only with `apt-get install r-base`

Comment: @AizuddinZali that just results in permission denied.

Comment: of course you need `sudo apt-get install r-base`.

Comment: @AizuddinZali then I don't understand your first comment.

Comment: well, that is common sense that you cant install anything without root priviledges. Try my suggestion and let apt resolve the dependencies for you.

Comment: @AizuddinZali I appreciate your help, but don't you think I tried the simplest solution first? apt-get install and apt-get update did not work.

Comment: put all work effort in your question, easy for us to follow what was done from your end.

Comment: @AizuddinZali I did link to the question that already describes the steps I followed.

Comment: ah ok my bad, was not saw it there..

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was trying another R mirror site. For some reason, the original site never worked and the error message didn't say anything suggesting this was the problem.